# wkhtmltopdf font not picked up on windows server

Tags: php, windows, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I've been using [PHP WkHtmlToPdf](http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/) and one of the fonts I have in the html is Century Gothic. On my development machine (wamp on windows 7) this is fine and displays flawlessly, however when putting this on a windows server 2007 machine, Century Gothic is not displayed when generating the pdf.

I checked to see if Century Gothic was installed, it wasn't so I installed it but unfortunately it has made no difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any other font on your OS? I am asking if only this font is giving your trobule?

Comment: Yep, calibre and century gothic are used and calibra displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create PDF files with custom fonts, just specify them in the CSS part of the template.

Example of my project root folder (so it works on windows and linux) :

```
$root = 'file://' . (System::isWindows() ? '/' : '') . str_replace('\\', '/', ROOT_PATH);
# windows output : file:///P:/www/project/
# linux output   : file:///var/usr/www/project/
```

Variable `$root` is assigned to template, where I use CSS to specify font that I wanna use (put fonts that you use into project, don't rely on system fonts):

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FONT_LOCAL';
        src: url('<?= $root ?>font/open_sans_regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    body, body * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'FONT_LOCAL';
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 24px;
    }
</style>
```

*For me this is best solution, because PDF file is generated with only this font, without that standard fonts that you don't even use, that means smaller PDF files.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glavic. I will certainly give that a try. However, it does leave me wondering why the font is recognized on a windows 7 machine and not windows server 2007 despite the same font being installed on both.

Comment: Don't depend on font installation on OS. Just put fonts into your project folder, and you won't have to think about fonts being installed on OS or not...

Comment: Yes, sound reasoning. I tried it and it has works! Many thanks Glavić, I'm very grateful for your help.